# does removing 'consequently' remove the causal relationship?

Tags: conjunctions

I am learning coherence and cohesion. Will the causal relationship between the two sentences disappear if I remove 'consequently'? If I remove 'consequently', will there be no relationship between the two sentences. Will they be read as separate sentences that are not connected?

> Their wealth of experience allows them to view situations from unique
> perspectives, which, in turn, can enhance innovation and
> problem-solving within an organization. **(Consequently,)** It is no
> surprise that large companies tend to hire seniors like Tim Cook as
> their CEOs.

(I wrote the text)

Comment: Yes, it removes the explicit connection, but common sense gives the reader the connection to the first sentence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, thanks for the comment. Is the subtle connection still a causal relationship?  I feel the use of 'consequently' is so pretentious.

Comment: Yes, a subtle causal relationship. Or use a smaller word: It is *then* no surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep saying in various answers "context creates meaning." Congratulations, your context has created meaning! Yes, the relationship between these two sentences should be clear to the reader: "Experience is helpful. Companies hire leaders with lots of it." The causal relationship can be guessed easily.

*But*, connecting words can still be useful. Starting the second sentence with "consequently," even without reading further the user is prepared to expect a causal relationship. But trust your gut: if the word feels "pretentious," pick a different one. Personally, I would encourage you to rework all of both sentences to avoid passive voice, corporate buzzwords, and vague terms. I encourage you to read [*On Writing Well* by William Zinsser](https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_Writing_Well_30th_Anniversary_Edition/mp16BDRDaYQC?hl=en&gbpv=0), which points out that corporate writing is its own culture that often perpetuates and encourages bad writing, but it doesn't have to be that way. There's nothing inappropriate about using a simple, clear tone even when writing about corporate topics.

Comment: __There is no passive voice in either sentence.__ Please do not promulgate the absurd notion that any weak phraseology must be the passive voice. And if you would have OP eschew the passive voice, then discard it from your own writing; there are two examples of it here: "_can be guessed_" and "_is prepared_." But don't worry, you're not the first to misuse the term. People have been torturing it ever since some poor soul first wrote that "the passive voice should be avoided."

Comment: @A.R. Ouch! strong words.